# Placing the content div above the jQuery UI ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

We are trying to place the content `div` above the jQuery UI ajax tabs. 
The jQuery UI for ajax automatically creates `div`s with IDs like `ui-tabs-1`, `ui-tabs-2` etc. And places the `div` below the UI tab list. I want to place the content which i get through ajax above the tabs.

Script -

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<div id="content"></div> <!-- i would like the content to be displayed here-->

<div id="tabs">
<ul>    
    <li><a href="content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `create` event of jquery UI tabs:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-tabs-panel').prependTo('.ui-tabs-nav');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Xh8nc/1/

Answer (score 0):

creat div like

```
<div id="content">
<div id="uitabs-1">
</div> <!-- i would like the content to be displayed here-->

<div id="tabs">
<ul>    
    <li><a href="content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```